# Problem solving a list creation in a new text filme comparing other two lists from other text files in Python

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble doing it on the PowerShell, so trying to do keep it on Python to make a .exe file and not depend on security issues from other user's computers.

Combine file1 not file2 in Debian or compare objects in powershell would be good solutions for my problem, but I just can't achieve it on python.

My python code is:

```
with caminho_php.open() as base_txt: # file with names from phpmyadmin
    for line in base_txt:
        lista_php.append(line) 

with caminho_local.open() as base_txt2: # file with names from Heidi
    for line in base_txt2:
        lista_local.append(line) 

for item_local in lista_local:    #search for each item in the local list
    status_item = False
    for item_php in lista_php: 
        if item_local == item_php: #compare them with each item from php list
            status_item = True
    if status_item == False:
        lista_final.append(item_local) #if the local item is not in the php list add them to a third list

new_file = ROOT.joinpath(f'select_{current_time}.txt') #make a new file to insert these items
with open(new_file, "w+") as new_txt:
    new_txt.writelines(lista_final)
```

If I write: 1 2 3 in the local text, copy it, paste in the PHP txt and just erase the 3 it still won't work and will return a third txt with both 2 and 3.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: By "1 2 3" you mean each number on a separate line, right? Have you tried other use cases, like equal files, totally different files, and so on?

Comment: yes, the numbers are just easier examples for the sql rows.
Totally different files no because that is a situation that would throw some error. I cannot have rows in the web server if they aren't in the local one. But equal files are just ok, it creates an empty text file.

Comment: você é Br né?hehe as vezes em pt facilita

Comment: Sim, porém escrevo em Inglês para que toda a comunidade possa participar. :-)

Comment: No problem! Just asked 'cause maybe would be easier for you hehe But about the issue, do you know what may be the problem? This script is actually copied and pasted from another project I made and that one had no problems at all to do what I needed.